# Unable to start Fabric on Mac OS, startFabric.sh gives daemon error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am following the setup as per https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html. But when I run `./startFabric.sh`, I run into error as per below logs

`docker ps -a`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                        NAMES
53263f6dc18e        hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.1       "peer node start"        20 minutes ago      Exited (1) 13 minutes ago                                                peer0.org1.example.com
8e558708b7f6        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.1    "orderer"                20 minutes ago      Exited (1) 13 minutes ago                                                orderer.example.com
0c373a640583        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.10   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   20 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes               4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp   couchdb
e86a4960ab44        hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.2.1         "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   20 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes               0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                       ca.org1.example.com
e30099dbd318        hello-world                         "/hello"                 23 minutes ago      Exited (0) 15 minutes ago                                                hungry_zhukovsky
```

`cd fabric-dev-servers/ && ./startfabric.sh`:

```
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'startfabric.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is set to 'hlfv12'
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
Stopping couchdb             ... done
Stopping ca.org1.example.com ... done
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
Removing couchdb                ... done
Removing ca.org1.example.com    ... done
Removing network composer_default
Creating network "composer_default" with the default driver
Creating couchdb             ... done
Creating orderer.example.com ... done
Creating ca.org1.example.com    ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
sleeping for 15 seconds to wait for fabric to complete start up
Error response from daemon: Container 
3e81f3aa41969a7ae3f7a09c5c42c16aa55e2527958aef319ad93988ca942f7f is not running
```

On checking the logs for this container, i see this error :

```
2019-09-06 09:27:49.868 UTC [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> DEBU 020 Reading directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts
2019-09-06 09:27:49.868 UTC [main] main -> **ERRO 021 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts: stat /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory**
```

I get the same error when I try to start the peer container from Kitematic

My setup is as per below:

- `docker --version`: **Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89**
- `composer --version`: **v0.20.9**

I found same issue https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4202 on Windows 10 however I am facing this on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Are you running Docker Toolbox for Mac (rather than Docker Desktop for Mac) as you are running OSX 10.11 ? It could be that that version of Docker has limitations and so it won't work. Suggest you run a hypervisor such as virtualbox and install a complete linux desktop distribution and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes that's correct. I am running Docker Toolbox for Mac. Oh, is that the only workaround.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is due to Docker Toolbox. If you can't run Docker Desktop for Mac (which is the newer version) then you will have to run linux in a VM I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

> 2019-09-06 09:27:49.868 UTC [main] main -> **ERRO 021 Cannot run peer
>   because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory
>   /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp: could not load a valid signer certificate
>   from directory /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts: stat
>   /etc/hyperledger/peer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory**

It Means running container cannot able to access the mounted certificates folder

Please check volume mount !! in the docker-compose file

Comment: Do you mean volumes:  
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/  
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx  
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp  
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users

Comment: Retrying couchdb request in 125ms. Attempt:1  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 172.19.0.3:5984: connect: connection refused
Giving this error